# Android: How to clear EditText on timeout?

Tags: android, timer, android-edittext

I want to clear EditText if e.g. 5 secs has passed from the last edit. I added a textChangedListener to the EditText. The textChangedListener then simply used a Timer that tries to clear the EditText in its run() method. However, the application crashes, because according to the debugger, EditText.setText("") is being called from "wrong thread". So, what's the best way to implement this behavior?

I have a Qt background and I cannot believe this is so hard in Android :) The Qt and C++11 implementation of clearing text edit widget on timeout is something like 3 lines of code.

Comment: Show the code you have in the smallest workable sample so we can look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the Timer runs on a background thread != from the UI Thread. As  quick fix, you can instantiate and Hander and use the `postDelayed` method. The runnable will ru on the Ui Thread, after the delay

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I managed to make it work with a Handler and postDelayed(). I'm not sure if cancelling the active callbacks works properly, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about if this will solve your problem but you can try to edit your edittext in your timer or a thread.

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            EditText.setText("");
                        }
                    });
```